# jQuery zoom page by simulating Ctrl +

Tags: jquery, triggers, zooming

I am new to jQuery. 
I want to zoom page by simulating Ctrl +/-

The reason I want to do this is, my page has a cocos creator canvas and if yours click on it, zoom events no longer work. 
My plan is to capture the event inside cocos and fire it back to document.

I have seen several posts related to this. 
But not clear how to do this.

I tried this, but it didn't work. Why?

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 107;       // Key code for +
e.ctrlKey = true;
$( document ).trigger(e );
```

There are other suggestions to zoom using styles

```
window.parent.document.body.style.zoom = 1.5;
```

This does work, but if user zoom normal manner (Ctrl +/-)
Then there is a mismatch of zoom level. 
eg style zoom maybe 1.5 but page zoom maybe 50%

What exactly happen when user click on Ctrl +/- ?

Can anyone suggest work around for this?

Comment: Given that the Ctrl+ is a user interfacing directly with the browser, and not the DOM/webpage, I would be surprised if this fell in the realm of javascripts control.  The ability for websites to change the zoom level of the browser, not the page (as you've demonstrated they are different), would give javascript access to override user preferences.  Which is not good UI.

Comment: Is there any way round this issue?